# Too many rows causing 500 error?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, http-status-code-500

I have 40k entries in a database, and I am trying to call them using a simple fetch in laravel.

```
$domains = Domain::where("available", 1)->limit(1000)->get();
return view('domains')
    ->with("domains", $domains);
```

This works fine up to a few thousand rows. But if I set no limit on the call, I receive a 500 error. I can't fathom why, and I can't work out where I would look to discover how to avoid this issue, I can't seem to find anything in the apache logs, or laravel's own logs located in storage.

Comment: If Apache serves HTTP 500, then there must be something in the error logs if you have error reporting enabled http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: You run out of memory that's allowed for a php script.

Comment: I'm willing to bet you're exhausting the PHP allocated memory pool. You'll have to paginate the results

Comment: You were right about the allocated memory. Clearly my setup was flawed somewhere or I've not understood where CentOS stores its logs as this didn't come up.  I will implement the chunk solution to avoid having to increase the memory pool too much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can avoid this issue by leveraging the `->chunk` command.

```
Domain::where('available', 1)->chunk(200, function($domain){
    //do whatever you would normally be doing with the rows you receive
    // $domain stuff
});
```

The purpose of the `chunk` command is to free up memory after every `X` iterations of the Model. In this case, I've shown 200.

*Sidenote* - As the chunk method uses a `Closure` as the 2nd argument, ensure you `use($your_varaibles);`

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that existed. The thing is I wanted to then use the $domains variable in a return view->with("domains", $domains); I'm not sure how to do that within the scope of the solution here, as I imagine simply moving return view into the chunk's scope would provide me with in this case 200 entries only. So I need to somehow pass them iteratively outside the scope? Small edit to explain

Comment: @DavidG Sorry for the delayed response - You can just push them into a collection that way you can loop and use them as usual in your views: Alias a collection ahead of time, like this: `$domains = collect([]);`, then inside of your loops, push them onto it, `$domains->push($domain);`. Then you can return `$domains` and use them in your view as per usual.